# How to preventDefault() when using submit()?

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I am trying to make a input field that submits when enter is pressed. When I try to use the submit() function I get the default page reset. I don't know how to cancel this. I have tried to use a event listener for submit and even passing a anonymous function into submit() but neither seems to work.

```js
addTask.oninput = () => {
    window.onkeydown = (key) => {
        if (key.keyCode === 13) {
            newTaskForm.submit()
            console.log(newTaskForm.addTask.value)
        }
    }
}
```

PS: if u think it is one of those I have already tried please say so. could have just messed up some syntax.

Comment: So.. you want to submit the form on enter yet prevent submit all together?

Comment: no i want to prevent reseting the page. thats what the function does isnt it ?

Comment: `submit` submits the form to the page in the forms `action` or itself if not set. Sounds like it is doing what it should. Else you might want to use xhr.

Comment: @TomášČikovský the page must redirect to submit the data to the server unless you submit the data with an ajax request.

Comment: let me explain again. I want to submit the form and then use data from it on the same page.  When we submit a form with a button we use  a preventDefault() function to prevent the page from reloading right? so i am asking how to use this function when using the submit() function instead of a button

Comment: If you use `preventDefault()` you don't prevent the *reload* you prevent *the form submission*. It's the form submission itself which causes you to go to a new location based on the form's `target`. If the target is the same page, then the submission will hit the same URL and just reload the page but you'd lose all the data. If you want to submit *and* stay, most likely you need to employ AJAX to send the data to the back end.

Answer (score 0):

```js
addTask.oninput = () => {
    window.onkeydown = (key) => {
        key.preventDefault();
        if (key.keyCode === 13) {
            newTaskForm.submit()
            console.log(newTaskForm.addTask.value)
        }
    }
}
```

key is actually an event in your code.

If you want to not submit your form after a .submit()

then you can use :

```js
newTaskForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) = > {
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Yes. `key`is an event here, yet that does sadly not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

yes so my fault i actually dont know what happend but i tried the answer before even submitting the question and it didnt work, probably just made some stupid mistake. sorry i wasted your time :D

Comment: So it does work now? If so, please mark this answer as complete or delete the question to not confuse other people.

Answer (score 0):

The submit function works like that and will always do that. So I should not use it and save yourself with javascript.